# How to align text to the left and math to the right inside an equation

Tags: equations

i cannot seem to find a way of aligning the text inside an equation to one side and the math itself to the other, while keeping both centered in the page. If someone knows how to do it, I would like to recreate what is shown in the image below (ignore the "Sellar problem" part). Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have set the words flush left, using `\intertext` but to set them aligned you can use a row of the alignment. I added `\notag` not strictly necessary as I am using the unnmbered `align*` version here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
 \text{minimize:}&\notag\\
f&=x^2\\
\text{where:}\notag\\
y_1&=z\\
y_2&=\sqrt{y_1}\\
\text{subject to:}&\notag\\
\frac{y_1}{3}&\geq 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Have a nice day!